# expressjs req.body is empty

Tags: express, body-parser

Banging my head on this. in Express app, my get request works fine. However attempting to POST results passes an empty req.body.

here is my file tree:
[image: file tree]

```
index.js:
const express = require('express');
const apiRoute = require('./routes/api/index.js');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// const morgan = require('morgan');

const app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.headers['content-type'] === 'application/json;') {
    req.headers['content-type'] = 'application/json';
  }
  next();
});
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use('/api', apiRoute);

app.listen(3000);
```

routes/api/index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const entityRoute = require('./entity');

router.use('/entity', entityRoute);

module.exports = router;
```

routes/api/entity.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const db = require('../../database');

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  db.select().from('entity').then(function(data) {
    res.send(data);
  });
});

router.post('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send(req.body);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Adding my Postman request in response to comment:
[image]

I have been over this numerous times, checked body-parser docs and other SO answers and can't figure this out.

following the comments, submitting json body works. screenshot below:
[image]

Not sure why this doesnt work the other way...

Comment: Could you also provide your http request / curl request? I'm sure it's fine but it's always worth double checking :)

Comment: Elliot, thanks, I just added what I see in Postman for the POST request. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: Can you show us the code from where you are sending http request?

Comment: Try sending data via body in json format

Comment: R.Sarkar, thanks. That request works as expected. I wonder why it didn't work the other way though?